# creation of a new script tag in shopify

Tags: python, django, shopify

I am sending the post request to https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/script_tags.json with the respective request body.

request body params below:-

{
"script_tag": {
"event": "onload",
"src": "my_link_to_script",
"display_scope": "order_status"
}
}

however i am getting the successful creation response. But the tag is not get inserted into my store checkout page.

I am inserting the image below where the tag should get inserted after the successful response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6pqv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/scripttag).

> The ScriptTag resource represents remote JavaScript code that is
> loaded into the pages of a shop's **storefront** or the **order status** page
> of checkout.

This script will be executed/appear only in Storefront and order status (*the last step of the checkout process*).
Also, this means that the script will fire when the user completes his purchase, the information before that cannot be gathered.

---

The script won't be shown in the admin, because this is mostly used for Apps, not related to the Admin interface.

That kind of script only can be seen with GET request to the same URL that you are posing new once:
https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/script_tags.json

Comment: okayy thanks kamenarov